# Updating an SQL table based on condition.

Tags: mysql

This is my table structure

```
Teams (Table Name) 
TeamID      TeamName       TotalScore 
01          Cowboys        6 
02          Bulldogs 
03          Broncos 
04          Raiders

Games (Table Name) 
GameID    team1     team2     team1score team2score Winner GameStart            Status 
01        01        03                                     02/04/2014 07:00:00    0 
02        02        04        6          10         04     03/04/2014 05:30:00    2

Users (Table Name) 
userID      Username      Password    Main Team   Points 
01          Brodey        abc         02          3

Tips (Table Name) 
TipID     userID      GameID       TippedTeam 
01        01          01           02 
02        01          02           03
```

If `game status = 2` check `Tips`. If `TippedTeam` matches the winner from `Games` then update `Users points +3`. If winner doesn't match, don't update.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
update users as u,  tips as t 
set u.points = u.points +3
where u.userid = t.userid 
and tips.tippedteam = (select winner from games where status=2)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN all the 3 tables, try this:

```
update users as u, tips, games as g
set u.points = u.points + 3 
where u.userid = tips.userid 
and tips.gameid = g.gameid
and tips.tippedteam = g.winner 
and g.status=2
```

For your second request (made in comments), try this:

```
update teams
join games
on teams.teamID = games.team1
set totalscore = CASE WHEN teams.teamID = games.team1 THEN IFNULL(TotalScore,0)+games.team1score ELSE TotalScore END
where games.status = 2;

update teams
join games
on teams.teamID = games.team2
set totalscore = CASE WHEN teams.teamID = games.team2 THEN IFNULL(TotalScore,0)+games.team2score ELSE TotalScore END
where games.status = 2
```

Update queries (above) combined into one:

```
update teams
join games
on (teams.teamID = games.team1 or teams.teamID = games.team2)
set totalscore = 
      CASE 
      WHEN teams.teamID = games.team1 THEN IFNULL(TotalScore,0)+games.team1score 
      WHEN teams.teamID = games.team2 THEN IFNULL(TotalScore,0)+games.team2score 
      ELSE TotalScore 
      END
where games.status = 2
```

Comment: Hello, i have one more query..i unable to write that too...
When status = 2 in Games it will need to update Teams team1 with team1score and team2 with team2score and + each time. Not replace but increase by for example 6 goals this game but 10 next game the totalscore should be 16.

Comment: can you please help me in solving this query

Comment: @AnkurDhanuka sure but I am unable to completely understand your second request. Please add more details in your question (with sample data and expected result) using the [edit] link. Thanks.

Comment: in this database...we have gameid 02 whose status is 2....now what should happen....team1 is 02 and team1score is 6....this score should be added in teams table i.e in teams table teamsID 02 whose score is 0 will become 0+6...same for team2 and team2score

Comment: @AnkurDhanuka i have updated my answer above with the query for your second request. I have not tested it, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @AnkurDhanuka please check my updated answer. I was able to do it in 2 separate update queries. Tried to combine them into one but couldn't succeed.

Comment: It sounds like this is a new question. Can you 'accept' the answer above as the answer to this question, and then ask a new question (with a link back to this one)?

Comment: @AnkurDhanuka i was able to combine the 2 update queries into one. I have updated my answer above.